# How to submit a form with JavaScript by clicking a class font awesome link?

Tags: html, laravel-5.4

Instead of a submit button I have a link:

```
<form action="{{ route('schools-list.destroy', ['id' => $school_list->id]) }}">
  {{ method_field('DELETE') }}
  <a onclick="document.form.submit"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove"></span></a>
</form>
```

Can I make it submit the form when it is clicked?

Answer (score 1):

the easiest way would be to create a  tag for the fontawesome icon and then wrap that in a  tag. Like this:

`<button> <i class="fontawesome class here"/></button>`

Answer (score 1):

To achieve what you are asking to do…

> ```
> document.form.submit
> ```

You need to:

1. Replace `document.form` with something that actually gets a reference to the form such as `document.the_id_of_the_form` (although `document.getElementById("the_id_of_the_form")` would be clearer).
2. **Call** the `submit` method instead of just mentioning it in passing (i.e. `submit()`).

---

However.

Links are supposed to link to places.

Forms are supposed to be submitted with submit buttons.

Use a submit button.

You can put HTML inside it and style it to look however you like:

```
<button><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove"></span></button>
```

… this will (a) not depend on JavaScript and (b) be announced as a submit button by screen readers.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a class and add onclick event to it and then submit the form

Comment: "You can use a class" — How would that help?